# Select multible records from custom relation list and send ID's to URL

Tags: case, salesforce-id

I've created my own custom object for attachment to case. The object name is Case_Attachment__c. I can upload files to this list.

[image]

The next step I want to do is to be able to have a button on my relation list that sends the selected attachments to a URL. Example URL http://someurl.com/8888/caseids=ID1,ID2,ID3 etc

[image]

Is this possible to do? How would this button be programmed?

Comment: What do you mean by send? Send the file id, or the raw content of these files? Are you hosting this app locally (I see the :8888, usually you need a port number for local apps)? Have you looked into creating a custom button? Does that not suit your needs? Why not? Theres a lot of questions behind "sending a file", that I think a detailed [edit] could answer.

Comment: I want to just send the ID's to a web service, not the file contents. 
The web service will then be triggered and fetch the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom button, configure it to allow selecting of multiple records, and then add the selected record ids to a url, and open it in the button.

Create a new custom button, and set the behavior to this:

[image]

You can use the function `GETRECORDIDS` to get the selected record ids from the page, and then loop over these values to format them (might be an easier way). Then, open your built url. Your app takes over the opened page, and should be able to show "loading" messages/close the window.

```
var ids = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Type__c)};

if (ids.length == 0) {
    alert('Please select at least one row');
} else {
    var url = 'http://example.org/8888/caseIds=';

    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        url += ids[i];
        if (((i + 1) < ids.length) {
            url += ',';
        }
    }

    window.open(url);
}
```